# for loop for iterating over a list of string

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, parameter-expansion

I need to loop through a list of strings, and use each word as parameter for my other functions,

```
PB_REGION_UPPER=NA,NASA

for region in ${PB_REGION_UPPER//,/}
do
   echo $region
done
```

I was expecting the result of this to be

```
NA
NASA
```

so I can pass NA and NASA separately to other function
however the result I got was just

```
NANASA
```

isnt supposes to /,/ separate two words here?

Comment: almost ... `//,/` replaces the comma with nothing so you get one string `NANASA` and your code becomes `for region in NANASA; do ...`; try replacing the comma with a space, ie, `${PB_REGION_UPPER//,/ }` so your code becomes `for region in NA NASA; do ...`

Comment: keep in mind if your comma-delimited fields contain spaces then those spaces now become delimiters, eg, `PB_REGION_UPPER='NA,NASA,OTHER NASA'` and `${PB_REGION_UPPER//,/ }` becomes `for region in NA NASA OTHER NASA; do ...` => 4 passes through the loop with 4 different values stored in `region` ... `NA`, `NASA`, `OTHER` and `NASA`